# How can I toggle between content on one page, without PHP?

Tags: php, css, hyperlink

I'm completely new to coding, so please bear with me. For my website, I am using this responsive layout template: http://purecss.io/layouts/blog/.

How can I link to and load different content (e.g. bio, contact, etc.) in the content area, without reloading the sidebar as well?

I host my website on Google Drive so **I cannot use PHP**, which I was told would be helpful here.

Comment: You need to look into AJAX requests for dynamic loading of the content.

Comment: You might also look at using Google Sites, that lets you specify top are (horizontal navigation bar) and a left side info along with your page

Answer (score 0):

PHP would be ideal really.

I don't like using iframes, but you could put an iframe in the content, and link to the content in the sidebar, making the iframe the target.

Use an iframe in the content with the first content you want to load.

```
<iframe src="bio.html" name="mainiframe" style="width:100%;"></iframe>
```

Put links in the sidebar to load the content in the iframe.

```
<a href="/bio.html" target="mainiframe">Bio</a>
<a href="/contact.html" target="mainiframe">Contact</a>
```

Comment: Can I ask why iframes are not the preferred method, vs. the AJAX or css suggestions above?

Comment: Theres a few reasons, but the main reason I dont use them is that the url doesnt change per page when using iframes. They dont help the SEO of a page either. Googlebot doesn't put the content of an iframe on the page.

Comment: Lets say I actually prefer that the URL doesn't change, and am not concerned with SEO - in this case would iframes be a more straightforward option than AJAX or css? I am also wondering: would iframes be compatible with a responsive layout?

Comment: As long as you had some CSS making the iframe width 100%, it should be OK. Or if you dont know how to do that, I have edited my answer to include the width. Iframes are a quick and easy option.